# Question about Frechet differentiability.

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Consider $F(f) = f^2$ with $F:L^2[0,1] \to L^1[0,1]$. We want to know if it's differentiable by Frechet.

So based on definition:

$$
\underset{\|h\|_{L_2} \to 0}{\lim}\dfrac{\|(f+h)^2 - f^2 - A(f) h\|_{L_1}}{\|h\|_{L_2}} = \underset{\|h\|_{L_2} \to 0}{\lim} \dfrac{\|h^2 +2fh - A(f)h\|_{L_1}}{\|h\|_{L_2}} = \star
$$

Choosing $A(f) = 2f$ we will have $\star = \underset{\|h\|_{L_2} \to 0}{\lim} \|h\|_{L_2} = 0$.

Is it true, or maybe I miss some part?

Comment: If $A(f)=2f$, should not the limit be one?

Comment: @温泽海 as far as I can see $\|h^2 +2fh - 2fh\|_{L_1} = \|h^2\|_{L_1} = \int h^2 d\mu = \|h\|^2_{L_2}$.

Comment: Never mind. I mislooked. Then everything you have done is correct.

Comment: Limit is $0$ so it is done. You can also show Frechet derivative is unique if you want.